# How booting from usb device works?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

After being able to make my flash drive and external hard drive (connected through USB) bootable (for windows installation) and thus changing the device boot order to the USB, I came to the conclusion that the PC will run whatever is in the USB device's root directory by default.

As a result of being curious tho, I removed my internal hard disk drive (the one which has windows installed on it) and connected it through the USB stick, changed the boot order to USB (1st boot) and connected my the drive through the USB cable.

It shows windows windows icon, attempts to boot as it would ever do as an internal hard drive, but after few second a blue screen get shown and restarts and the restart loop continues infinitely.

I was quite curious and would  like to ask about how booting from a USB stick works? Why the blue screen? Is the the data to be transmitted too much for a USB a USB device?

Comment: This is a surprisingly difficult question to answer (and I can only hypothesize - I don't have the exact answer), but its not that too much data is transmitted across the USB.  Reading https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-does-windows-10-boot I wonder if it is an issue handing off from the Windows OS loader to the kernel - particularly if the kernel does not have USB drivers built in and loads them later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was quite curious and would like to ask about how booting from a USB stick works?

Exactly like booting from internal HDD. There's no difference. In legacy mode, the master boot record stored in the partition table will be executed. In EFI mode, the configured loader or default loader (if present) stored in the FAT filesystem will be executed.

> Why the blue screen?

Because Windows isn't designed with this in mind and can't handle it. There was a [Windows To Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) feature that could be enabled on Windows installations to make them bootable from USB, but it was removed from latest Windows versions.

---

Bonus question: if *"there's no difference"*, how come *"Windows isn't designed with this in mind"*?

On the boot stage, both internal and external storage devices are just that, storage external devices. The firmware treats them identically. The operating system, however, can have different logic paths for handling miscellaneous devices. Windows does. Linux, for example, does not.